# Is it possible to check if a system is on LAN vs WiFi via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, electron

Are there any packages for node that can determine if a PC is on a LAN vs Wifi connection?

I have gone through the node docs and it doesn't appear there is a native node module. (https://nodejs.org/api/os.html)

Could not find anything in NPM that could determine this either.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can run any bash command you want using `exec`.

So you can do something along the lines of

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function main() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('tail -n+3 /proc/net/wireless | grep -q .');

 if (stdout) { // wirelesss }
}

main()
```

Adapted: [determine if connection is wired or wireless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590874/determine-if-connection-is-wired-or-wireless)